# Negation like symbol with text/numbers underneath

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

@Werner has marked this question as duplicate, but I do not feel the original question deals with the detail of the result as Heiko has given.

The answer marked here provides more detail and a more robust solution.

I'm transcribing some work for a professor of mine and I've come across something that I've never encountered before. I'm trying to reproduce the subscript of this

[image: The subscript on the S is what has me confused.]

I'm sure I could manage this with Tikz, but I am wondering if there is any other way to accomplish such a thing?

Comment: When I say `other way', I mean more elegant solution. Tikz seems more like the brute force way to accomplish this.

Comment: The quality of answer(s) here have no bearing on the duplicate-ness of the question. This question is a duplicate of the other one since it asks for the same thing; moreover, there are some reference in the current answer that is also suggested in the mentioned duplicate (yes, sometimes the questions may be different, but the same answer identifies it as a duplicate). People who find this post will also find the other post (and vice versa), since they are linked through their duplicate tag.

Comment: @Werner As I understand it, questions are duplicates. The same answer to different questions wouldn't make those questions duplicates. The questions have to be (essentially) the same.

Comment: @cfr: I'm biased towards the possibility of the opposite notion; seemingly different questions that lead to the same solution (read answer) may have a duplicate *theme*. Sure, themes are not questions, but working with people here we have some grey areas within which to make decisions. I've mentioned this before in [Duplicate vote clarification](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5656/5764). For those who disagree with the closure, they are more than welcome to vote otherwise. This question is a clear duplicate for me, even though Heiko's answer provides more detail.

Comment: I'm pretty new here, so I'm just wondering, but doesn't that make [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89490/annuity-or-angle-operation-symbol-in-latex/) some how a duplicate of this too?

Comment: @Werner Oh. I thought it was just stipulative on the part of SE.

Comment: @Werner I don't necessarily disagree with the claim this is a duplicate, by the way, but only with the reason (given what I understood the definition to be).

Comment: @Francesco That's on a different site, so it can't be marked as a duplicate, I don't think.

Comment: @cfr: [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/168244) is some relevant discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example implements the lines by basic TeX means, two boxes and two lines. The procedure is explained in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\NegationLike}[1]{%
  \mathop{%
    \mathpalette\@NegationLike{#1}%
  }%
  % A little space is added automatically,
  % if a math ord atom follows.
}
\newdimen\BarLineWidth
\newcommand*{\@NegationLike}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: argument
  \vbox{%
    % The rule thickness of \overline or \underline
    % is available in the font dimen register 8
    % of the math family 3 of the current size.
    \BarLineWidth=%
      \the\fontdimen8%
      \ifx\displaystyle#1\textfont
      \else\ifx\textstyle#1\textfont
      \else\ifx\scriptstyle#1\scriptfont
      \else\scriptscriptfont
      \fi\fi\fi
      3\relax
    % The rule at the top
    \hrule height\BarLineWidth
    % Move the box with the vertical line
    % as height as the top of the upper line
    % to get a better corner.
    \kern-\BarLineWidth
    % First save the formula in a box.
    % Then the height can be manipulated
    % later for the space between the
    % formula and the upper line.
    \sbox0{%
      % The formula (#2) in the current math style (#1)
      % without additional space around the formula (\m@th).
      $#1#2\m@th$%
      % A little space before the right line, adjust
      % to your taste.
      \kern2\BarLineWidth
      % The vertical line automatically stretches with
      % the height and depth of the box.
      \vrule width\BarLineWidth
    }%
    % Increase the height of the box to get
    % some space between the formula and the upper line.
    % TeX uses three \BarLineWidth in \overline and
    % \underline. The fourth \BarLineWidth compensates
    % the negative kerning from above.
    \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0 + 4\BarLineWidth
    % Output the box.
    \copy0 %
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\[
  Rs_{\,\NegationLike{14-(-1)}\SI{1.5}{\percent}}(1 + \SI{1.5}{\percent})
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

TeX uses a cramped style, if a formula is below a line (denominator of 
a fraction, root, ...). Cramped style means, that TeX tries to reduce the height, for example, if there are superscripts. It can be forced by macro
`\cramped` of package `mathtools`:

```
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\NegationLike}[1]{%
  \mathop{%
    \mathpalette\@NegationLike{#1}%
  }%
}
\newdimen\BarLineWidth
\newcommand*{\@NegationLike}[2]{%
  \vbox{%
    \BarLineWidth=%
      \the\fontdimen8%
      \ifx\displaystyle#1\textfont
      \else\ifx\textstyle#1\textfont
      \else\ifx\scriptstyle#1\scriptfont
      \else\scriptscriptfont
      \fi\fi\fi
      3\relax
    \hrule height\BarLineWidth
    \kern-\BarLineWidth
    \sbox0{%
      $\cramped[#1]{#2}\m@th$%
      \kern2\BarLineWidth
      \vrule width\BarLineWidth
    }%
    \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0 + 4\BarLineWidth
    \copy0 %
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

## Alternative: Package `actuarialangle`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{actuarialangle}
\begin{document}
\[
  Rs_{\angl{14-(-1)}\SI{1.5}{\percent}}(1 + \SI{1.5}{\percent})
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result actuarialangle]

## Package `stix`

The package defines a math accent `\annuity`, but works for a single symbol, not larger expressions, therefore a changed example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
\[
  Rs_{\,\annuity{n}\;\SI{1.5}{\percent}}(1 + \SI{1.5}{\percent})
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result stix]

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on, but I cut and pasted it, and it works perfectly!!

Wow that's perfect. What a great answer! Thank you!

Comment: I realize that this notation is common in financial mathematics. In the answer you have given it seems you created the solution by creating a new command, which is great, it works. I can't help but wonder though, is there or do you know of a solution that financial mathematics uses that is not your solution, perhaps a standard method?

Comment: @Francesco Perhaps the person whose work you're transcribing could point you to any specialised package which might be useful?

Comment: @cfr The mathematician I am working for, while proficient in LaTeX, is happy to outsource the work that I am doing, I need to be able to come up with my own solutions. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89490/annuity-or-angle-operation-symbol-in-latex/) question which seems like a duplicate of mine, but the answers given, in my opinion, are not satisfactory. I linked this solution, which I think is phenomenal, and posted Heiko's solution.

Comment: I understand that the mathematician won't want to be pestered every time you are stuck. Not much point in outsourcing in that case. But asking for a pointer to any specialised packages relevant to the relevant fields seems perfectly reasonable. Such packages will not necessarily be widely known among LaTeX users generally, may be available only from specialist sites and would usually be the preferred solution when typesetting work in the field. Otherwise, you are going to end up with *ad hoc* methods which are not standard approaches in the field. That's good for nobody.

Comment: @cfr agreed. I think I will ask him. I found a package called biosik on ctan which seems to contain this exact solution in a much more elegant manor, simply using \annuity{n}, but I'm still learning LaTeX and putting \usepackage{biosik} in my preamble did not allow its use. I couldn't figure out how to install it on my mac.

Comment: @Francesco A search for `biosik` on CTAN revealed nothing. But I found two packages in TeX Live grepping for `annuity`, see updated answer.

Comment: @Francesco Can you post a link to the package?

Comment: @cfr I realize I made a typo, it's not biosik it's boisik. My apologies.

Comment: @Francesco The only CTAN search hit is [`boisik`](https://ctan.org/pkg/boisik), bitmap font in alpha state, written in Metafont, without any relation to financial mathematics.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek table 215 from [The Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) names this package. After our further discussion I was able to come up with better search parameters to find other similar discussions to this question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89490/annuity-or-angle-operation-symbol-in-latex/)),  which again, does not answer the question as fully as I feel it is done here.